# Smaller Image on Retag Questions privileg

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, help-center, privileges-page

The image on [Retag Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/retag-questions) for displaying tags can be smaller. It is displayed in its full width of 1374px.